# Was Nuada Airgetlám accompanied by dogs?

Tags: myth-identification, celtic, irish, god-items

According to [this passage from a website](https://www.petyak.com/dogs/general/articles/dogs-in-mythology/), it's stated that the Irish war-god and *Tuatha Dé Danann*'s first ruler Nuada Airgetlám was sometimes accompanied by a pack of dogs whose licks are said to have healing powers:

> "In ancient Irish mythology, there are numerous references to dogs
> suggesting that dogs held a special place in the early Celtic culture
> there. The god Nuada, known for his healing powers, had a pack of dogs
> to help him. The dogs were also magical and could heal people by
> licking their wounds."

Nothing I've found so far suggests that Nuada was accompanied by these dogs, expect for repeated mentions of his British counterpart Nodens, who was a hunting god that was symbolised by dogs and a throwaway line from [this translation](https://storyarchaeology.com/revisiting-sinann-in-the-metrical-dindshenchas/) of the *Dindshenchas'* third volume that makes mention of a *Cú Núadat* (*Gaeilge* for *"Nuada's Hound"*), suggesting that Nuada had something of a dog motiff attached to him.

> Dénum aile, is mebair lemm,
>
> rochúala cách co coitchenn;
>
> Cú Núadat, ba mór maise,
>
> robáite ‘sin chrúad-glaise.

Is this an singular objective answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my studies have found what you have found is all there is. The association is strictly based on the common understanding that Nuada is the post-christian Irish descendent of the Celtic god Nodens. Lugh and Cú Chulainn are the figures that are most associated with dogs in Irish myth. Their rise in prominence and might explain the lack of association with Nuada.